# How to call a method in the main thread from another thead in a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to create two anonymous pipes (for read messages from and write messages to another process), a window (roughly a message-only window) in the main thread (but not using the windows forms or wpf way) using the win32 `CreateWindowEx`. Since there is a window, a message loop and `WndProc` is also needed. (At this time I don't know how to do both in C# but not in C/C++, it is not a problem, my concern is not them.) In this `WndProc`, it deals with some customized messages, these messages from another process. Once the read thread received a message, it can send that message to that message-only window, some action must be taken to response this message. Some pseudocodes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // 1. Create sender pipe
    // 2. Create receiver pipe
    // 3. Create a thread for receiving messages from another process
    // these messages are in the form of customized messages.
    // 4. Define a window class struct. 
    // 5. Register the window class  
    // 6. Create a message-only window
    // 5. Enter the message loop
}

// Only for describing this problem, it is not C# code because I dont how to express this WndProc function in C# :( sorry
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_MSG1:
        // some logic here for WM_MSG1
        break;
    case WM_MSG2:
        // some logic here for WM_MSG2
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);   
}
```

But for me now, the reading messages thread is not the same thread as the main thread (creating window in this main thread), I need to call that `SendMessage` in the reading messages thread, but run in the main thread. How to achive that in C#? thanks for kindly.

Comment: *wait the other to finish but don't block* it doesn't make sens ... *So the main thread must not exit or blocked (or the main thread could be unresponsive).* why ? there is nothing to make it "unresponsive" it doens't have UI ... it is not possible to call something back on main thread as main thread doesn't have some kinde of message queue (like UI programs have) ... This seems like XY problem

Comment: maybe you wana call something on another thread and get results on another (every time on the same) ... https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134870/simple-dispatcher-implementation/134878#134878 https://dotnetfiddle.net/nlQaJj

Comment: @Selvin You are right. I dont describe my problem clearly. What i want to do is that (I dont know how to achieve it in C#), I want to create a window using some function (that function use the win32 CreateWindowEx function to create a window) in the main thread, when that function create a window, it also create some threads to receive message from another *process*, then once message received, that thead call some method in the main thread. I want to  implement this logic, but dont know how to do that.

Comment: if you create window then you have to build [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues) ... then all you need to do is create custom message `WM_USER + X` and process it in WndProc of this window ... it will be called on window thread

Comment: @Selvin thanks, I try to implement this.  in fact, I want to create this window in a single process, after finished creatation, that window handle will be send to another process, reparenting it to a window in another process.

Comment: I would suggest to include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72431189/how-to-call-a-method-in-the-main-thread-from-another-thead-in-a-console-applicat#comment127956023_72431189) comment that you posted earlier in the question (by editing it), because it seems to be essential for the problem that you are trying to solve. Questions here are supposed to be self-sufficient. They should include everything one needs in order to answer them.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am going to do that.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have edited it. Can this question be reopened?

Comment: I casted a [reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) vote, although I don't have the expertise to answer your question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks all the same. if my question cannot be reopend, is it appropriate to post a new one with the same content?

Comment: If it's exactly the same question, even with different wording, the probabilities are that it will be closed shortly as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I will not ask this question again for now. thanks.